# Programming with ADD/ADHD

Tags: productivity

I have diagnosed ADD.  Mild but enough to affect my work:

- Easily distracted
- Can't concentrate on one project at a time
- Addicted to the web
- Procrastination
- etc.

What strategies do you use to compensate?

---

**One clarification**

I have **real**  ADD.  I was diagnosed with it when I was a child and have wrestled with it all my life.  I am not talking about **artificial** ADD, which is induced by media overload.

---

### Update

I just read this description ADD/ADHD.  It's a great description, especially for us programming ADDers:

> I am like a toolbox,
>   with all the tools I will ever need
>   lain gently and neatly in the box,
>   ready for me to use them.
>   The toolbox is translucent
>   so I can see them there.
>   
>   The key to the toolbox is locked inside of it.

Comment: Dosnt really sound like an ADD problem. I seem to have all of those problems :P

Comment: Don't we all have these problems? At least sometimes? Doctors like to slap names on things.

Comment: Please don't patronize the OP.

Comment: I definitely have this and consider that I may have mild ADD/ADHD. Stackoverflow definitely doesn't help...

Comment: You've just diagnosed _me_ with ADD!

Comment: Thanks for this post.  It's good to see others open with their issues, which I share with you in this case.

Comment: "SHUT UP AND STUDY!!!"

Comment: Google the personality type INTJ

Comment: I love this post

Comment: What you need to do is figure out. Oh look a bird! I feel hungry. I wonder what I'll watch tonight on TV? What was I doing?

Comment: I'm a programmer with ADD as well, and I've tried a lot of behavioral fixes as suggested below. Then this past month I started on medication and everything fell into place.  I'd say start with behavioral, try it for a few months and if you don't feel it's helping enough, then add medication. Add it, don't just rely on it, 3 months will form behavioral habits and then the medication should fix the underlying medical issues.

Comment: @Chris :  What medication are you using?

Comment: @lamcro Concerta, actually a generic of it.  Doc explained it as working like Aderall, except it's actually more available (apparently a lot of places don't have Aderall available).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I've had similar problems as you do. The two main strategies that have helped me are

- **Only one project at any time:** I've suffered from following more projects than I can count on my fingers, each "clamouring" for attention. Now I've radically cut down on projects either by finishing them "once and for all" or by simply dropping them altogether. Earlier this year I've founded a company and now I'm down to three projects: Health, Family and Company.
- **Separation of concerns:** When doing everything on one desk, the risk is high to "drift" from one thing to another. I've removed all procrastination stuff from my work PC and use my Laptop only for "play" and other private internet usage (mails, [userfriendly](http://www.userfriendly.org/), [slashdot](http://slashdot.org)). The PC is on my desk, the Laptop in the Living Room. This keeps a healthy distance between Company and private stuff.

Of course these two things are quite general stuff. Some of the smaller, but also helpful things:

- **No Lurking on IRC/other chat channels.** Either I need or give support/community in the project I'm working on or I'm not in that channel.
- **Close The Mailer.** Checking mails because the project just compiles is just stupid, since waiting for a compile is just enough time to see whether or not there is mail. If there wasn't any mail, I've interrupted my flow for nothing and if there *was* mail, I'd either have to interrupt my flow even more to handle it or punt it anyways. So now, I'm checking my mails three times a day and have reduced my interruption count significantly.
- **Exercise.** Often while programming I feel the urge to jump up and run around in my room. Especially when sitting before the tougher design decisions. Going biking every other day has significantly improved my ability to concentrate on stuff as well as the added benefit of improving overall stamina and well being.
- **Spent Time Bookkeeping.** I've got a simple spreadsheet where I enter my Company time and some private stuff. I keep it to 15 minute chunks, which makes data entry much easier and any smaller units just cause more overhead. If I'm not doing something I can "bill" on the Company and it's between 8:00 and 18:00 I know I'm doing something wrong.
  Also, at the end of the week I get a nice report how I spent my time. One **big caveat** here though. When I started this after finishing university it was a hard blow for me how little time I was spending "productively." It took me quite a while to recognize, that I need to record everything I don't do for Family. Specifically:

  1. I need to record times spent exercising as productive. See above.
  2. I need to record times lost due to external factors: I'm travelling a lot lately and when I've only recorded 25 hours of work in a week, I suck. But if I add the two days I spent on the road that week, I see that I did more than 40 hours. Suddenly "I suck" changes into "the external-factors-that-cause-my-travels suck," which is a much healthier thing to say.
- **Eat and Sleep Regularly.** Stand up at 07:00, Breakfast, Lunch at 12:00, Dinner at 18:00, Sleep from between 22:00 and 23:00.
- **Appreciate the Small Successes.** Even if I'm not yet there, today is better than yesterday and tomorrow will be better than today.
- **Adjust you Environment.** That's quite a broad topic. As a home worker, I got myself a nice new desk and chair which I now use exclusively for work.
  Also I really like listening to music, but vocals -- especially in my mother tongue -- distract me incredibly. I've tried instrumental music, which worked for a while until the trance beats got to my nerves. Now I'm going for the complete silence. It might be different for you, but there's only one way to find out for real: experiment and watch yourself while working.
- **Become Accountable. Get a Conscience.** I founded my Company together with an old friend, whom I deeply respect. By his presence and by knowing that our success is now is interlocked, I feel compelled to give my best.
- And finally **Constant Vigilance!** Distractions tend to creep up from every nook and cranny of your life (stackoverflow anybody? ;). Keeping them at bay and managing them will stay a constant struggle. Having said this, I have to close my stackoverflow tabs and get back to programming!

---

**PS:** I've talked with someone from my family who is working with ADHD kids. She told me that ADHD is a kind of catch-all/fallback diagnostic (see [the ADHD Wikipedia entry for corrobation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention-deficit%5Fhyperactivity%5Fdisorder#Diagnosis): DSM-IV V.) and is hard to diagnose "scientifically" since the patient has to be monitored in different settings over a longer period of time AND other causes for the symptoms have to be excluded. Practically ADHD is handled as "the condition helped by the prescribed medicines", since there currently are no globally accepted non-[psychiatric assesment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychiatric%5Fassessment) test procedures and not enough knowledge about the underlying biochemical functions. Again, quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention-deficit%5Fhyperactivity%5Fdisorder%5Fmanagement): "There are several effective and clinically proven options to treat people with ADHD. Combined medical management and [behavioral treatment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior%5Ftherapy) is the most effective ADHD management strategy, followed by medication alone, and then behavioral treatment."

From what I gathered from the discussion with her, the problem is that doctors often choose (cheap, symptom-oriented) medication over (expensive, cause-oriented) therapy with little regard to the long-term effects on the patient.

Comment: "Separation of Concerns..."  I've even switched to "one PC for development another for internet, mail, etc."  It works wonders.

Comment: That's a great list. I've experimented with listening to white noise while working, it does cut out a lot of the audio distraction. I found an hour of white noise in MP3 format which I just play on loop.

Comment: I love the idea of white noise.  I'm constantly searching for the right mp3 to allow me code without distraction.  Sound isolating headphones are a requirement.

I think these ideas apply to many, not just those with ADD. EMail is my killer distraction, and keeping Outlook closed helps.

Comment: The one that is personally most important to me is having someone I trust to whom I am accountable. Thanks for the list.

Comment: Honestly, your list sucks. That's nearly completely the opposite of what I do. +1, I guess. Meh. Time to change my life.

Comment: @Konrad: I'll take that as a compliment. But let me tell you that being a student offer degrees of freedom never experienced again, so don't take it too seriously ;-)

Comment: I bump this in the headphones. http://www.simplynoise.com . Choose from white, pink, and red/brown noise.

Comment: Ya, simplynoise has the stuff you need.
I recommend the brown noise as being less distracting.
it sounds like rain on the roof.

Comment: @ThomasGHenry, you might want to check out bands such as Merzbow or Aube

Comment: @ThomasGHenry, thanks, I tried it out and enjoy it. I found that the rain.simplynoise worked better for me, very relaxing. They have rain as a seperate page along with randomized thunder. Best one I've found!

Comment: I was diagnosed yesterday with mild/moderate. I'm going to start up an exercise program right away, I fell off the Crossfit bandwagon, but am ready to give it a go again and see if it helps improve. Seems like reading indicates the most effective natural treatment is lots of exercise.

Answer (score 34):

Use the development methodology named *eXtreme Programming* (XP). It's a **lightweight, low-ceremony, high-discipline** methodology. Specifically, use **pair programming**, which will help you focus and let you drift away for periods if you have to, without hurting the progress of what you're doing. But don't partner up with someone with ADD. ;]

Also, everyone who belittles the condition should help themselves to a nice cup of STFU.

Comment: Pair programming will work wonders for this.

Comment: "help themselves to a nice cup of STFU" -- love it. +1

Comment: "a nice cup of STFU" = awesome!  +1

Comment: -1: It seems as if you are trying to apply XP to solve any and all problems.

Comment: @Jørgen If you by "any and all" mean the problems that are clearly listed in the question, then absolutely, I'm confident pair programming (and the specific properties of XP I mentioned) can solve them. :)

Answer (score 21):

I'm a total newcomer to this board (introduced by a programmer friend), and my work is in the field of psychiatry, not computers. I told my friend that the comments on this thread are some of the most intelligent offerings I've seen with regard to ADD and the problems associated with challenging work like programming. As a 62 year-old professor of psychiatry at a major medical school, I can say with some confidence that you guys are offering one another some very sound advice. Even some of the gripes and complaints have pearls of wisdom in them. Naturally I have my own biases and beliefs about all this, being a shrink, but I even agree with some of the negative comments about my own profession. Doctors are not always helpful. The bottom line from the standpoint of good science and evidence-based medicine is that what David S. says in the first post (above) makes a lot of sense. Medication can be very helpful, even life-saving, and certainly career-saving, but it has to be used wisely and prescribed by a thoughtful, caring clinician. Using other substances like marijuana and alcohol can be a slippery slope leading to disaster. It's a challenge being as bright and capable as you guys are, and life is never easy for people who are smart enough to look past the daily grind, thinking at the philosophical level. Thanks for creating this forum!  John T.

Comment: Glad to see comments from a professional of your field.  Any advice you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I find it *such* a challenge being so incredibly smart! :) Kidding (sort of) ... thanks very much for the post.

Comment: +1 for the encouraging comments about the self-help here and also from your professional standpoint.

Answer (score 20):

Turn off your web browser so you cannot access StackOverflow during work hours.

Comment: I find the irony of posting this question to SO very amusing :)

Comment: http://www.stayfocusd.com/ helps me with this: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji

Answer (score 19):

I agree with the comments made.

**I am a real believer in the non-existance of ADHD**.

This is normal behaviour. We ALL get distracted (just some easier than others - it's not a freaking DISORDER), one problem is that we have easy access to one of the most distracting things ever created, the Internet. We can get almost anything  we want within seconds!

The best thing you can do is get back to baby steps. Create a list of real small tasks, work down the list. The second you realise you are doing something else that is not on the list **STOP**. If you struggle to get back to what you were doing, move to another task. If the tasks are small enough, it shouldn't create an issue (unless of course there are dependencies).

Dude, ignore the god damn doctor. You have already taken the first step saying "*I want to be a programmer and stay focused on my job.*" Start small, stay on task, if you come off, don't beat yourself up, just get back on to it.

If it gets real bad, take drastic measures, disable websites that you dont *need* to do your job. (like YouTube, but not MSDN if you are a MS dev).

TBH, there are people in my workplace without "ADHD" that need to take a leaf from your book.

---

### Update Following Comments

There have been several comments made stating something similar to, or along the lines of the following:

- I don't know what I am talking about.
- My aforementioned friend is wrong/unqualified to make such comments.
- I am just simly wrong.

My responses to those would be:

- My friend has the right to say what they like, it's their opinion, much like it is your right to comment arguing against it.
- If you want to start debating against my comments, you have **missed the point**.

**Like I stated, I *personally* do not think ADD/ADHD exists. However, even if it does, it does not stop us from BEING IN CONTROL OF OUR OWN LIVES.**

The original poster has made the first step in becoming a great developer, I know lots of developers, but the ones I hold in high regard all share one thing in common: **they are looking to remove their weaknesses**.

The original poster is doing this, and certainly get's my respect for that, I simply tried to offer some advice to them. Getting stuck in the trap in accepting "there is not a lot you can do about it, just take your pills" is a fundamental weakness of attitude.

Hats off lamcro, and I wish him the best of luck, and if you ever need any more advice mate, feel free to ask. I'll support you much more than I would support the Doc.

Comment: ADHD doesn't just mean you're "easily distracted". It is a *chemical imbalance* in the brain that makes it much more difficult to concentrate, make good decisions, and so on. Your answer boils down to "suck it up and just try real hard" which is not in any way helpful....

Comment: (continued) I am the father of two ADHD kids, and I assure you it's not "normal behaviour". Without the medication that they take, my kids have a much more difficult time making good choices than other kids. The medication brings them to the level of "normal behaviour".

Comment: No, the answer is that they conviced you that you have ADHD/ADD and you bought it because you trust the doctor. Giving a name to a set of symptoms, does not mean that the "illness" really exists.

Comment: I've seen stories on TV about great dancers(and other artists) that in there youth would have been diagnosed as having ADD/ADHD - but then, the "illness" didn't have a name ;).

Comment: Guys, can we please stop the flame war. I have expressed my opinion here, but I am clear that its my opinion. I have a friend who was also diagnosed with ADHD, and he even thinks its not real.

Comment: I couldn't agree more!!  Where's the evidence of this "chemical imbalance"?  Do they run bloods tests for this diagnosis?

Comment: Someone diagnosed with ADHD doesn't make them an expert on the validity of its existence. ADHD is diagnosable using the DSM-IV diagnostic manual and patients with ADHD have different MRI brain scans than those without ADHD.

Comment: Hmm.. I understand that some people may disagree with my answer, fine, its called opinion, but why is it being marked as offensive?!

Comment: There are neurological tests done like EEGs. You opinion is fine. I equate it to Tom Cruise's "PPD is a state of mind not a condition" Total crap.

Comment: ADHD is over diagnosed, but it is real, there are studies showing differences in brain MRI and even in EEG readings. Like many conditions some suffer more then others. You can have a sever case of a mild one. Self discipline helps, but it is still going to make it more difficult for a ADHD sufferer.

Comment: Guys it's his opinion.  I even upvoted it, and I'm the OP.

Comment: secrtean: There are no blood tests for epilepsy, manic depression, autism, or multiple sclerosis either. Doesn't mean those conditions don't exist.

Comment: Assume that in the spectrum of mental behaviors, there is a set outlying on the normal distribution that obstructs some people's ability to deal with normal activities and these behaviors aren't solvable by willpower. Label that set ADD/ADHD and treat it.

Comment: Ran out of room: Many mental "disorders" are only defined by a set of behaviors. The criteria for ADD/ADHD goes way beyond "spends too much time surfing the net and puts off tasks". If drugs and behavior therapy helps, who cares if it's a "disease" or a physical/chemical problem?

Comment: It matters because what works as treatment for ADHD is absolutely destructive, even deadly, if you don't have it (and especially if you have some of the symptoms for other serious reasons.)

Comment: Telling someone with ADD to just focus/whatever is like telling a "fat" person to just eat less and exercise more.  It sounds good to non-"fat" people, but it's useless advice.  The person has heard that 1K times, and would be non-"fat" if it was that simple.  Advice givers: Take you worst habit/problem and eliminate/fix it in the next week....

Comment: Although I respect your right to have your own opinions, I would like to share a bit about myself: I was not diagnosed with ADHD until I was 24. I had a neuro-psychological battery performed on me, which is about as close to objective as we can get with these things, and afterwards I was asked if I was lying. I have an extremely low dopamine response when compared with the average person.

Before starting on ADHD meds, I had zero finished projects. While I'll agree that my condition does not stop me from controlling my own life, medication improves the quality of it greatly.

Comment: Your 'opinion' belittles those who have to deal with the condition. Over-diagnosis is definitely an issue however because it takes legitimacy away from those who seriously need help. Much like how overblown accusations such as Jennifer Livingston's "bullying fiasco" takes attention away from people who need help like Amanda Todd. It's not like we who have ADD are asking for you to give us breaks, we just want recognition, which has routinely been given through science.

Answer (score 14):

I wasn't diagnosed ADD as a children but was close to it. Apparently I'm OK now as an adult, even though i still can become easily distracted. A few hints:

-Stay off the stimulants: coffee, coke, chocolate, etc.

-Don't listen to music. I've found music screws my focus A LOT (it seems to help others, 
but doesn't work for me).

-Stay off the web. Don't keep tabs open on slashdot, digg, every man and his dog's blog or whatever. Just keep an eye on your important email inboxes and google for stuff you need for your work. Delay idle browsing til after work or lunch time.

-Use the 'one step at a time' approach to procrastination. In short, instead of facing a big task, break it down into smaller parts and say to yourself 'i'm going to do this mini-task and then i'll take a break'. You'll see it's easier to do it this way. Same technique as 'i'll just wash a couple of dishes from the stack', and then once you're doing it you just go ahead and do the whole stack. Works for me all the time.

-Take a break every now and then, but not every 20 minutes. A break every 1,5hours works for me (relaxes your eyes and lets you relax for 5 minutes).

Comment: Stimulants like caffeine and amphetamines are actually beneficial for ADHD as they increase levels of dopamine which helps with concentration.

Comment: Caffeine isn't particularly useful for ADHD and using it as such can be very detrimental to your health.

Comment: Yea, caffeine hypes me up but doesn't help with concentration. Methylphenidate does a lot more to help maintain focus.

Comment: My doc defines coffee for ADHD as "self-medication" - it's actually a indicator before you're diagnosed.

Answer (score 13):

- Get a big white board and position it where you can easily see and access it.
- Make sure that you have SEVERAL things to do.
- Write each one on the board, leaving room for notes underneath.
- Pick one and start working on it.
- If your mind wanders - jot down any ideas under the topic you're leaving.
- Pick another topic.
- If any ideas about other topics come to mind, record them immediately and try to get back to what you were doing.

Comment: I am doing the same thing.  I can frequently move them off the white board, and plop them into google notebook, where i can ignore them.

I find that having 2 - 3 tasks available, makes it so i have something to do when I need to wait for one of them.

Answer (score 13):

Anyone who gives "advice" on how to overcome a REAL subset of conditions is a fool AND unsympathetically cruel.

It's like saying to someone Multiple Sclerosis doesn't exist, and just saying to someone just walk!  It's easy, just put one leg in front of the other, and JUST walk.  Forget what the doctor says, you can do it if you think positively... utter rubbish!

Example: some people are naturally more thick skinned than others, and yet they DARE "teach" others how to be laid back... lol how delusional.  Someone's psychological traits are NO different than their sporting abilities, e.g. coordination and balance.  If Tiger Woods came to someone with poor coordination and just "taught" him how to be a great golfer it wouldn't happen, even if taught from a young age... sure the person would be better if taught... but you are fighting against someone's natural abilities.

A better example might be mathematical ability... I find maths quite easy but some people don't.  I find drawing REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY hard!  I enjoy it but it's just unbelievably hard... I've had artist friends try and teach me and sure I've improve BUT I'm still really lame!  Some people have the same teachers and yet produce VERY VERY different results... this is because everyone has different natural affinities... anyone who doesn't agree with this is delusional.

The problem with modern society (particularly America) is that so many people believe that if you try hard enough you WILL succeed in anything you try... here's the latest newsflash... absolute BS.  A lot of people can't admit this.  The REAL key to success is finding something that fits your NATURAL abilities, and then doing that as a career... if you work hard at that you have a good chance of being moderately successful, but some people will not do well even if they play to their natural skills, as their best skills might not be that good.

My message is that if you're good at something (and that includes neurological skills that most people take for granted like "focus" and "organisational skills") then don't think that just because it comes naturally to you that someone's difficulty doesn't exist.  Only an utter fool would act that way!

Sure SOME people DO make excuses, but the majority of people I meet are doing their best.  Indeed I would argue that EVERYONE is doing their best given their nature / nurture, e.g. their gene's, their upbringing and environment.  It takes both intelligence and empathy to understand this... if you don't then one of those is missing... harsh of me to say but it's true.

Comment: Wow one of the best answers I've ever read here! +1

Comment: Lot of truth here. Read Martin Seligman, or read (recent info) about genetics. We have instincts and abilities that are innate, and that differ from person to person. Make the most of what you have, and stop feeling shame for not being what you or others think you should be.

Comment: Many people should have that printed, framed and nailed to their forehead :-)

Comment: So your answer is that the OP shouldn't be a programmer? If not, then I'm not sure I understand the relevance here.

Comment: +1 on the money. -1 doesn't answer the question, so +/-0 from me.

Answer (score 13):

There's one aspect of ADHD that appears to be being neglected here:  [hyperfocus](http://www.additudemag.com/adhd/article/612.html).  It's a common misconception that ADHD means that you can't pay attention to things.  In reality, people with ADHD have trouble regulating what they pay attention to.  This can play in your favor though.  People with ADHD can be totally oblivious to things that would totally destroy a "normal" developer's ability to pay attention to things.

I find that it's more difficult for me to get into the "zone" than other developers, but once I'm there, it's diffuclt to get me out.  I've been known to start coding and then look down at my watch and realize that I just spent hours hammering out code without ever thinking about doing anything else.

In fact, I would say that a bigger issue for me is that I tend to go for long periods of time coding and neglect to take care of basic necessities.  So make sure that you take a break every once in a while, don't skip meals, and drink plenty of water!  (the last two are even more important if you're taking medication)

Comment: I do this too, and I've always wondered if this is really what "hyperfocus" means. How strongly of an indicator of ADHD is this?

Comment: The ADHD --aka ADD-- brain (specifically the prefrontal cortex portion) craves stimulation, be it through stimulant medication or through a very stimulating piece of code that you're programming -- heck even the endorphins generated by exercise can do the trick!  If you find something interesting enough to concentrate on, you can hyperfocus on it for hours and hours.  However, if you are forced to complete a task that is uninteresting, it can be very difficult to focus without the aid of additional stimulation.

Comment: I know this supreme-zone state but, unfortunately, occurrences seem to be years apart for me.

Comment: You nailed it as far as "real" ADD goes. Most of these comments are right, EVERYONE gets distracted. But how often do people get so wrapped up in what they're doing that they don't realize hours go by, they're starving, and the wife is pretty pissed. I bet people wish they COULD but it's not as easy as just switching in it on and off, if we could then we'd be supermen. It's highly irregular and requires a lot of stimulation and interest, everything else falls to the wayside not matter how bad you "want" it. That's "real" A.D.D. in a nutshell.

Answer (score 9):

I was diagnosed with ADHD when I was 10 or so.  For the past 16 years I have been on a myriad of medications and therapies to deal with it.

I have had many problems with trying to work when there are even slight distractions.  I used to rely on Adderall to stay focused, but would find myself getting **too involved** in projects at times.  I have stopped taking any medication (a little over a year now) and it has been hard to deal with, but very rewarding.

I find it easier to keep myself focused when I have a **good nights rest** and have a **scheduled routine**.  I wake up at the same time every day (weekends included) and use my breaks to the fullest.  Playing footbag during breaks is a great way to distract yourself and get exercise at the same time.  I do find myself straying from time to time, but everyone gets distracted sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

I probably don't have as ADD as bad as you, but I've found that the 48/12 rules works quite well in general. So work for 48 minutes and then take 12 minutes off, then start again.

I also tend to have several projects ongoing so I work on the one my thoughts have turned to for the day. In general, I find that if I have enough things open in my dev environment, I end up being distracted from one project by another, rather than a browser.

Sometimes that may not work however, so I've found that identifying (and writing down if necessary) several different ways to get yourself started and away from the browser\tv etc is handy. I think they'll be quite specific to you. For example, perhaps taking up a GTD approach so you always have a list of things to do will help.

One last thought - you might want to repurpose your browser's parental control settings so that you can only browser, say, your mail and a couple of programming sites during workign hours and remove that temptation.

Best of luck, Dan

Comment: The GTD method is partially fine. But it has it's issues. One thing is the walkthrough of the inbox. It is very easy to jump on every sub 2 minute actionable item (because all of them seem to be quick to complete) and suddenly you find yourself yak-shaving. But the lists are very find.

Comment: A problem with the browser settings, are that I depend on stack overflow at work, and I am also completely addicted to it :)

Answer (score 8):

I used and still use Ritalin, but really just a minimum daily dose. I am 33 now, my condition was only diagnosed in adulthood.

The problem is not so much the ADD, but the side effects, especially depression and anxiety, and that can have a very bad impact on productivity.

My suggestion is: Go see a doctor/shrink, and if he prescribes you Ritalin (or something similar), try it. Ritalin has a very short half-life and normally is out of your body within 12 hours. I do not believe it has any long term side effects, unless you abuse (overuse) it.

Alternatively, you can try some calming medicine (or other calming herbs).

Comment: Good for you. My son has ADHD and Tourette's, and has been on a cocktail of meds, including Ritalin and Concerta, for most of his life. That stuff really works, but an MD should monitor it.

Comment: I might add that I've taken flying lessons and found out that many pilots are ADD. The reason is that flying requires not focussing too long on any one thing, but monitoring several things at once.

Comment: +1 for the pilot comparison. Wow. Never thought of it like that. Perhaps that means a career change for some here? Am I in the wrong job!

Answer (score 8):

Even if ADHD is a "personality trait" or a "personality flaw" and not something with an easily-identifiable chemical cause in the brain, the end result is the same and the need for solutions is the same.

And either way, it's not something anybody should use as a crutch or an excuse.  We all have strengths and weaknesses and those of us with ADHD have a very peculiar and particular set of them.

That's why I find the ADHD naysayers totally misguided.  Who cares if it's "real?"  There are studies that suggest that there are indeed physical phenomena in the brain unique to ADHD, but like I said, that's besides the point to me.

I used to think ADHD was a scam to sell medicine to kids (mis)raised by crappy parents. Perhaps that's true to a certain extent, but I'm pretty sure nobody's getting rich from the $20 generic Adderall my doctor prescribed me. Anyway...

**Non-Tech Solutions**

My biggest single leap in dealing with mild ADHD (inattentive type) was reading the book "Getting Things Done."  While not specifically written for those with ADD, the core message of the book is a set of concrete methods to reduce mental clutter and focus on the task at hand.  Valuable to all, I think, and particularly so for ADHD sufferers!

My second biggest leap was reading books like "You Mean I'm Not Lazy, Stupid, Or Crazy?"  Some things in the book will apply to you and some won't. For me it was really just important to know I wasn't alone.

My third biggest leap was getting prescribed stimulant medication. There are a number of medications and they all have drawbacks but the stimulants seemed to have the mildest ones. This was an important step but pales in comparison to the other two.  No medicine can compare to learning coping skills and working hard and believing in one's self.

**Tech Solutions**

Hiding the browser or disconnecting the Internet doesn't work for me because I need to consult it often.  Blocking specific known timesucking sites (like S.O.!  haha) was somewhat effective for me.

Another thing that works for me, and might sound slightly odd, is using virtual machines.  My OSX laptop is my general-purpose computer.  But the Win 2K3 VM running in it is "for work" and putting that in fullscreen mode helps me focus on work.  In the VM I just have Visual Studio and other development tools.  No "toys" or IM.

Working at night helps a lot because there are less distractions.  Obviously, it's not always practical.

Investing time and money in keeping my machine optimized helps.  If I have to wait more than a second for something to happen I can get distracted easily.  When my computer is fast and snappy I can use it at the speed of thought.  I seem more concerned with this than your average person so maybe this doesn't apply to you.  If this does, install at least 4GB of RAM and an SSD if you can afford it.

Most of all, good luck!  ADHD is beatable and has probably given you some genuine gifts, such as hyperfocus, as well.  Find out what you're good at and work to your strengths.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try organizing your time into small and simple tasks

Answer (score 5):

Within the methodologies of eXtreme Programming, there is a technique called [Pomodoro Technique](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/) which is "**a timeboxing strategy originally meant for optimizing personal work and study**". The technique "**is a time boxing strategy people can apply in any situation, e.g., homework, study, cleaning house, and indeed software development**". I think this may help you focus your efforts.

Within Agile software development methodologies, the Pomodoro technique is usually held in high regard.

In essence, the technique was invented by someone who suffered from the alt-tab syndrome you describe, and it successfully helped them counter this.

Answer (score 4):

**One clarification**

I have **real**  ADD.  I was diagnosed with it when I was a child and have wrestled with it all my life.  I am not talking about **artificial** ADD, which is induced by media overload.

Currently I am seeing a psych and using Strattera.  Also, I exercise a lot.

I used to do Martial Arts, which also helped, and would like to do it again.

Comment: I like Strattera.  None of the ups and downs of stimulant-based medications.

Comment: I agree, I take it as well. ADHD has been a struggle but like everything else you have to make it work for you.

Comment: I wish Strattera worked for me.  I've been on stimulants for a few years now, and its very difficult to separate myself from them.  I do on weekends if I don't have work to be done, and have tried during the work week, but I only became very tired.

Comment: I tried Strattera last year and hated it with every fiber of my being. It was the first ADHD meds I'd ever tried and will never touch it again. I'm glad it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I too have trouble concentrating and getting things done. What i do is i listen to very busy and active music. Like Drum and Bass or Rock, my brain is listening to all the small nuances of the song and it acts like a calming effect for me.

With the music on i feel relaxed and focused. But of course this could be the opposite for you :S

Comment: Statistically signficant correlation between two things that I know of:

1. Software development skills,  
2. Musical skills.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting thing

Comment: Listening to music helps me too to concentrate on one thing. I usually listen to music with complex rhythms, like progressive rock with weird time signatures or maybe some IDM. I know I have some musical skill too. 

It seems that whenever I hear music I can't ignore it. And if it's boring (e.g. radio) it annoys and distracts me.

Answer (score 3):

I dont suffer from ADD myself but I am very easily distracted while working so I can sympathize with the OP.

However I have found a very novel solution to the distraction problem while researching another problem that I do suffer from (RSI, aggravated by badly set bone breakages in both arms)

The solution I found was http://www.workrave.com/welcome/ which is a program you can program to alert you to take mini breaks at user specified intervals.
I found that setting it to give me a 30 second break every 15 minutes means that I can concentrate for the full 15 minutes and then when the alert pops up I can take a break and allow my distractions to take over.

There is a countdown for the minibreaks so as it approaches 0 I can force myself back into the mindset I need to concentrate for another 15 minutes.

and of course it has the added benefit of forcing me to take breaks to prevent my RSI from flaring up.

Answer (score 3):

I am a programmer and have been for the last 8 years and I was recently diagnosed with ADHD! Also, I am a REAL programmer, in that I can program in Assembly Language, as well as these OOP's that call themselves programming languages. Even taught myself, Java and Perl last summer. You probably don't have a clue, what Assembly Language is, right? Well, I am able to program down to the bit! Granted it is an old ancient language, there is not one language that is more powerful out there (my opinion)!

Unfortunately sometimes, we feel that our opinions are correct when in fact they are very far from the truth! People with ADHD are able to focus and concentrate on levels that far exceed the "normal" brain; it is called hyperfocusing. Knowledge is power, so educate yourself before giving awful advice and opinions that have no merit.

Comment: And they can often concentrate on more than one thing at a time. In fact, what's deadly is boredom.

Comment: Hmm... you sound self-taught. That is very dangerous. I'm self-taught myself, and there is a huge risk of missing out important stuff. I'd advise actually getting a degree, or at the very least, doing what I did and finding out what you'd be learning for a degree, and learning it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably know your condition best, but here are some suggestions.

Take regular breaks. This applies to everyone, but even more so, I'd think, for someone with ADD.

Get enough sleep and eat well. If you don't, your attention span will be even worse, and you don't need that.

As for procrastination, read up on some blogs about procrastination, there are a bunch of good things written about it, find out what works for you.

Web addiction is a tricky one. I had a friend with ADD that used dual monitors, one for "fun" and one for work. That way he'd be able to tell when he spent too much time on the funitor ;) Your mileage may vary on this though.

Are you on some medication? Is there any or is your disorder too mild? Ask your doctor for advice, perhaps he can recommend some good meds :)

All in all, take care of yourself. Being well fed and alert is never a bad idea.

/Ace

Answer (score 2):

I knew someone who claimed that doing several things at once (or at least receiving several inputs such as music and TV) while working was actually **helpful**. He was qualified in physics but worked as a programmer.

Comment: I find it hard to work without talk radio on. Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

My 2c

First off, being in the same boat, and being a successful developer of projects both in a professional and private environments I can tell you that there is nothing stopping you from ADD / ADHD need not be an obstacle for your development. In fact, it can often be a bit of bonus as ADD people tend to create different relational links in their heads (this can be a good thing for inspiration / innovation, but a bad thing when trying to maintain the same view points as others).

Something that might help is to look more at ideas like Agile programming (particularly XP) and also using TDD, as the short turnover time can give you the inspiration to keep focussed. You are always working at something and if you want you can choose different parts of the system to work on at different times. The continues refactoring and improvement of the code will give you a sense of accomplishement that you might otherwise not get when taking a traditional waterfall approach.

Answer (score 2):

Today I decided to give up being a programmer :(  I am technically very able and academically very intelligent (according to my previous work colleagues and bosses).  However my focus issues and disorganisation is so severe that I rarely finish a project.

It really sucks.  It has always felt like I have a brand new Ferrari... but I've lost the keys, so I have to drive an old banger.  That is how frustrating it is having some great skills at something but being too disorganised to utilise those skills :(

Good luck to you though... I wish I had the focus and organisational skills required to be successful in life.  It pretty much ruins my whole life.  It's even hard keeping a social life in tact.  I will quite often forget friends birthdays and such even though I'm really caring as a person... if you have memory issues though people think you don't care :(

I know someone with a photographic memory for dates who ALWAYS remembers everyone's birthdays or anniversaries or whatever... and of course he LOOKS more caring.  Life is so f£$%ing sh!t if you have severe ADHD.  It f£$%s up your whole life :(  It's worse than being physically disabled!

Comment: Is this while diagnosed and under treatment? Sounds grim ...

Comment: Don't feel bad! i've been there often! This may sound corny or something, but it's true: what's on the inside that counts, not the outside. Plus, i know someone who has a severe physical disability, and i can tell you it's no different.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not qualified to offer any medical advice, as a perpetual graduate student I can say that a lot of time it's about playing a game of control with yourself.

If your problem is that you go online every minute just to look at some random site because you have a real urge to, it is sometimes effective ot make the cost of "instant gratification" higher: For example, I try to completely turn off my network when I can (not all workplaces allow this). I only go on between tasks and for a few minutes. Usually connecting to a network takes 30-40 seconds, so it often battles the urge.

Another way is to promise yourself a "gift" after you're done with a task: a break, a cigarette, a snack, a game of Halo, whatever... And you know that you're not getting to that unless you finish that unit of work, that helps reduce time spent online once you do go online.

Answer (score 2):

One way to increase the difficulty of distraction is to map offending sites (like this one ;) to 0.0.0.0 in your HOSTS file, effectively blacklisting them.

I've done this at times, it helps raise the mental barrier between me & distraction.

Answer (score 2):

I also have ADHD served with depression (cold) .. I was diagnosed early age, Ritalin kinda stuff also existed back then but my real problem was the notoriious Tourette's syndrome. So the doc (several docs) did not want to prescribe me with ritalin. So I graduated "as is" from the high school. Then later, somehow I lost that great respect to doctors, thank God and started taking Ritalin. But that happened after I was introduced to marijuana :) Sad story goes on like that ... People always used to tell me I was smart but I was kinda scared to take the IQ test. .. maybe I was afraid of seeing the potential i have and looking back to my life, what I have done with it and suicide. The parmanent solution to a temporary problem some may say but pain hurts. The score was about 140 and I said to myself I will start programming, the advanced LEGO as I see, the only thing I really loved as a child. Object Oriented satisfies this enthusiasm I have and I learn new stuff when I can + feel like to ... I use Ritalin, when ritalin (aka the Kid coke) kicks the depression in I give a call to mary jane .. Thats how I am living ... My point is I think we need our own developer froum as we do need "our own approach" for everything in life .. That includes women :) peace!

PS: A programmer might need high concentration levels, as you need high speed for inter planetary travel but the speed is never enough huh :) Maybe our weird ways of connection making may help bending the space for you guys ...

Answer (score 2):

Proper nutrition, sleep, and hydration are extremely important for proper mental functioning. Cut back on coffee and sugar and drink water regularly. I've heard numerous times that Omega-3 fatty acids (found in Cod Liver Oil) and magnesium supplements are known to greatly reduce ADD symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Are you SURE you're doctor is a good one ? I mean .. from what you say I have ADD too :| .

But I still get my job done even if after an hour I have to stop and look at stackoverflow or dotnetkicks ... or walk around in the room , or talk to one of my team mates .

So .. don't worry ,you can be a programmer just fine.

Comment: If you can still get your job done, then you don't have ADHD.

Comment: That's not true, @Jeff. He said that his ADHD was mild. Also, with more severe forms it's still possible to work, given enough treatment and self-discipline.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that people with ADHD couldn't work. I see now that my meaning wasn't at all clear. Sorry. I meant that there's a gulf between having some symptoms and having a diagnosable form of the condition, and I think sometimes people don't understand that.

Comment: There are several good books and web sites with checklists for ADHD symptoms. It's easy to find one and do a quick self-check.

Answer (score 1):

Three interesting facts:

There is a statistically demonstrated high correlation between productive (especially outside-the-box) software development skills, and diagnosis for ADHD.

To OP: I think the best thing on your list is having someone you trust, to whom you are accountable.

ummm ... I can't remember the third ...

Comment: + 1 for making me LOL with "ummm ... I can't remember the third ..."

Answer (score 1):

I shut mail down periodically during the day.

I have my shooting hearing protectors with me at work.  When I am wearing them, I can't hear the 4-8 conversations going on around me.

I have a a sign on a strip of duct tape that I can use to block the entrance to my cube.

The sign is a parody of our not-at-work sign that says  "I'M OUT OF MY MIND, PLEASE COME BACK LATER"

Answer (score 1):

Get professional help. and I'm not being cynical. I know people who's life turned upside-down since they started using Ritalin.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous said: "No, the answer is that they conviced you that you have ADHD/ADD and you bought it because you trust the doctor. Giving a name to a set of symptoms, does not mean that the "illness" really exists"

What a fool!  ALL illnesses and conditions are a set of symptoms that a name tag is attributed to.

Let's give an example... cancer is a name given to a set of symptoms, but it doesn't mean that this "illness" really exists.  Dur!

Whether you call a set of symptoms ADHD or X does not matter.

Example:

Say there are 3 symptoms, A, B and C.

One could describe an illness as follows:

Illness X = {A B}  Illness Y = {C}

Or

Illness P = {B C} Illness Q = {A}

As a doctor I could treat illness P by helping symptoms B and C, or I could treat illness X by treating symptoms A and B.  So it doesn't always matter what labels we use.

The REAL issue in how to label conditions is how symptoms statistically occur together in the general populace.  e.g. does symptom B often occur with symptom A?  If so it would be sensible to designate it as illness X = {A B}...  BUT if symptom A rarely occurred alongside symptom B then that designation would be foolish.  Anyone can see this surely!?

So the real questions to work out if an illness "exists" are as follows:

1) Do the symptoms themselves exist?
2) Do enough of the symptoms statistically occur together more than say 60% of the time (or whatever) in the general populace?

In ADHD's case 1) and 2) seem to be true.  Therefore it exists!  Simple as!

If you're going down your route of reasoning then we get in to foolish philosophy.  Does a chair exist?  It's just an arbitrary name for a set of "symptoms", e.g. 4 legs, and a back... but would then a table with a piece of wood nailed to one side to be a "back" then be a chair and if not why not!?  You get my point, it's easier to get along in the world if we have some understanding of what a chair actually is.

It's the same with illnesses... especially neurological ones, as we currently understand the human brain less than 1%... so it's our best shot!

Another one might be PTSD, you might say it doesn't exist, but as a label it is useful in treating people with a particular subset of symptoms.  If you don't understand what I'm trying to say then forget it.

You can't disagree that the symptoms of ADHD exist, and statistically it has been agreed that the symptoms of ADHD occur together enough to be useful in diagnosis.  Once someone is labelled as having such a condition they can then use that SHORTHAND to be treated by professionals that specialise in that particular label.

To highlight this there are subset of illnesses within higher level illnesses.  e.g. cancer usually designates some form of tumour(s), but there are so many different types of cancer... but why?  Because they need to be treated differently.

The problem with MOST human beings is that we often don't believe someone's difficulties until WE experience them directly!  I am evolved enough to give people who seem to be genuine the benefit of the doubt... but hey I work at empathy, as it's certainly not a natural state of most people.

Heart disease is a set of symptoms too!  Maybe that doesn't exist either lol.

As a human race in general we need to improve our empathy skills.

Comment: It's not an illness, it's a syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have ADHD as well... I find it helps though, let me explain. First and very important is work on one project at a time, yo can multi task on that project but it has to be the same project, so the brain doesn't go to overload. I actually found that people with ADD/ADHD (judging from myself and my friends with it) are great brainstormers. I will sit down to work on something to say make 1 feature, at the end with my mind all over the place it will turn to 10 features, or 7 different implementations of that feature. Very important though is noting, when you mind starts going somewhere else, write down what you're doing. I've noticed by writing your brain starts "hypothesising" on different thing related to the project. I've also noticed that occasional breaks help too, something systematic, for example every hour get up for 5 minutes and get a coffee. Also contrary to the previous statement cut on your stimulants, i.e. coffee, energy drinks, etc. It's hard but will help quite a bit

Answer (score -1):

I really don't think you can be a programmer if you suffer from ADHD - sorry.... Considering the necessary high-concentration levels.

I've been accused of hating or being negative.

This is nonsense, I feel great sympathy with anyone suffering from such problems.

I am just pointing out that programming requires higher concentration levels than the norm, yet ADHD means you have lower concentration levels than the norm.

So programming will be a problem. I'm being honest. There are many other good careers in IT, such as design work, that wouldn't require high concentration levels.

If you can solve the ADHD then programming would always be an opition again.

UPDATE:
Now I'm accused of saying high concentration levels means you are smarter!!!

Again, that is nonsense. I don't see that correlation necessarily.

Comment: OP already *is* a programmer with ADHD. Hating doesn't help.

Comment: Although it can be a challenge to be a programmer with ADHD there can also be advantages. Many people with ADHD can sometimes experience moments of hyperconentration where they're super-focused while in the zone. Having a disability shouldn't discourage someone from doing what they enjoy.

Comment: Exactly.  Just look at Ty Pennington. The guy from extreme makeover home edition.  He has AD(H?)D, but when he locks himself in his project room, and focuses on doing just one thing, he can get amazing results.

Comment: I think you'll find several references in this list (and I'll add my experience) to the fact that ADHD lets you hyperconcentrate on the right types of tasks, and programming is one of them. (Two others are video games and music.) Would that affect your point of view?

Comment: @Oak: Actually, programming is what I can concentrate most in.  Everything else (documenting, meetings, time-managing, etc.) is what I stumble on.

Comment: Honestly I think you should study what ADHD *really* is before drawing your conclusions (and posting them as an answer). ADHD will cause you to suck more at some task and excel in others, but all in all it will still be up the the individual skills of that person.

Answer (score -1):

Get prescription drugs like Adderall or Ritalin. Careful though because they're highly addictive.

Comment: Maybe his doctor should prescribe that? Those drugs are no joke.

Comment: Yeah, that's why they're *prescription* drugs :)

Comment: For someone with an ADHD-type brain, they are not typically addictive. People with ADHD react to stimulates in a completely different manner than people with normal brains. This is one reason why ADHD deniers are full of...misinformation.

Comment: here is a napkin to wipe away your tears jeffrey l whiteledge

Answer (score -2):

I have ADD, I am a programmer, and I use timeboxing as my main time management technique and it works well for me.   I also wrote a windows app that automatically conversts todo lists into a timeboxed list with an alarm and progress bars.  Here's a link: http://ericjorgensen.com/TimeBoxer.html

Comment: Please read the FAQ entry on [Self Promotion](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)